# How to use psql to restore database with relations?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to restore database using psql. But it seems like psql always fail when it encounter `CONSTRAINT`. After I look into the dump. I found out that the child table, the table that hold `FOREIGN KEY`, is created before the parent table.

Here is the snippet...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "answer";
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS answer_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE answer_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 START 71 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE "public"."answer" (
    "id" integer DEFAULT nextval('answer_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    "text" character varying NOT NULL,
    "weight" double precision NOT NULL,
    "questionId" integer NOT NULL,
    "baseCreated" timestamp DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    "baseUpdated" timestamp DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_9232db17b63fb1e94f97e5c224f" PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_a4013f10cd6924793fbd5f0d637" FOREIGN KEY ("questionId") REFERENCES question(id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE
) WITH (oids = false);
```

psql command.

```
psql -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5432 -U foobar -1 foobar < foobar.sql
```

And the error.

```
NOTICE:  table "answer" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
NOTICE:  sequence "answer_id_seq" does not exist, skipping
DROP SEQUENCE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ERROR:  relation "question" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "answer" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "answer" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "answer" ("id", "text", "weight", "questionId", ...
```